# Why does the content of my Drupal dynamic display block disappear?

Tags: drupal

The dynamic display block (image gallery) at the top of [this site](http://justfemme.in/) only shows the first content properly. The next one is lost even though it loads in HTML. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

IMO everything works ok. Maybe you should try View Slideshow if you getting still problems?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out myself.
The fonts were made bold in the article before publishing. I dont know what i had to do with the styling but the contents were getting shifted up behind the logo. I removed the formatting and it worked like a charm :)